# Solana Token transfer works in localhost but not on server

Tags: solana, solana-web3js

So I have a option on my site to "send" xy amount of custom solana token with connection to phantom wallet.
This exact same function works in localhost but not when I upload it to my server and go to the website through the ip adress. How is this even possible when this code is executed client-side in the same browser and the code is the same but when using the website hosted on the server I get:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'digest')
In function myToken.getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo
Using

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@solana/web3.js@latest/lib/index.iife.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@solana/spl-token@latest/lib/index.iife.min.js"></script>
```

In the headers

Here is the code:

```
function sendCOIN(amount){
    return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
        const publicKey = window.solana._publicKey
        const toWallet = new web3.PublicKey("myWalletPublicKey")
        const myMint = new web3.PublicKey("myMintAdress");
        const myToken = new splToken.Token(
            connection,
            myMint,
            splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            publicKey
        );
        const createTransferTransaction = async () => {
            const fromTokenAccount = await myToken.getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(
                publicKey
            )
            const toTokenAccount = await myToken.getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(
                toWallet
            )
            let transaction = new web3.Transaction().add(
                splToken.Token.createTransferInstruction(
                    splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                    fromTokenAccount.address,
                    toTokenAccount.address,
                    publicKey,
                    [],
                    web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL*amount
                  )
            );
            transaction.feePayer = publicKey;
            console.log("Getting recent blockhash");
            const anyTransaction = transaction;
            anyTransaction.recentBlockhash = (
              await connection.getRecentBlockhash()
            ).blockhash;
            return transaction;
        };

        const sendTransaction = async () => {
            try {
                const transaction = await createTransferTransaction();
                if (!transaction) return;
                console.log("Sending transaction!")
                const { signature } = await window.solana.signAndSendTransaction(transaction);
                console.log("Submitted transaction " + signature + ", awaiting confirmation");
                await connection.confirmTransaction(signature);
                console.log("Transaction " + signature + " confirmed");
                return resolve({signature, publicKey: publicKey.toString()})
            } catch (err) {
                console.warn(err);
                console.log("[error] sendTransaction: " + JSON.stringify(err));
                return reject(500)
            }
        };

        sendTransaction()
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a missing SSL/TLS certificate/no SSL enabled:
https://github.com/exiled-apes/candy-machine-mint/issues/126